# How to get Minimum and Maximum Price from Hibernate Search

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

I want to add filter functionality for products like most of the e-commerce website has..How should i get min and max price according to selected category?

I have implemented product filter search using hibernate search with spring boot data JPA...I am using Boolean query builder to create dynamic query according what actually user selects from filter..Let take example...Suppose i am selecting Men's Clothing category and i got results of product belonging to clothing category with left side filter also..Suppose in that category i only allow to select price range slider 100 to 100 which means min product price is 100 and max is 1000...After that i am filtering product data using left side filter like size and brand etc..If i selected one brand then again data is refreshed with new price value which is min and max of clothing products with brand category only..How should i do in hibernate search??

```
FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);

QueryBuilder queryBuilder = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder()
                .forEntity(Product.class).get();

Query categoryQuery = queryBuilder.keyword().onFields("subcategory.category.categoryName").matching("Clothing")
                .createQuery();

BooleanQuery.Builder builder = new BooleanQuery.Builder();

builder.add(categoryQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);

FullTextQuery query = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(builder.build(), Product.class);
query.getResultList();
```

Above is the sample code in which i am selecting all product of category..In this how should i create query to get min and max price from selected category and with adding extra filter will again change my old price value..please give me suggestion..I want same functionality like most of the e-commerce website have for filtering products or there is another way to do this???..Thanks in advance..

Comment: I suggest a query for the minimum and maximum values, rather than getting all the values. Let the database do the work, it will normally be more efficient and will avoid a possible Out Of Memory condition if there is too much data.

Comment: @JonathanRosenne : Yes ..but problem is selecting 4 or many brands in filter i cannot use this query..this will return min & max of column or of selected category..when applying filter with one or more conditions how should i get min & max according to filter what i applied??

Answer (score 0):

There is no feature in Hibernate Search allowing you to get the min and max (that would require aggregations), but fortunately there is a feature that should match exactly what you need: [faceting](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#query-faceting).

In short, this allows you, before the query, to define several price ranges, e.g. `[$0, $10)`, `[$10, $50)`, `[$100, $200)`, `[$200, $500)`, `[$1000, infinite)`. Then hen you get the query results, you will also be provided with the number of matching documents for each range, allowing you to present the user with appropriate filters (and to hide ranges that do not contain any result).

You will need to add something like this to your entity:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class Product {

    @Field(analyze = Analyze.NO) // You already have something like this, make sure to set analyze = NO
    @Facet(forField = "price", encoding = FacetEncodingType.DOUBLE) // You need to add this
    private double price;

    ...

}
```

Then you should [reindex your data](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-batchindex).

Then write your query like this:

```
FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);

QueryBuilder queryBuilder = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder()
                .forEntity(Product.class).get();

Query categoryQuery = queryBuilder.keyword().onFields("subcategory.category.categoryName").matching("Clothing")
                .createQuery();

BooleanQuery.Builder builder = new BooleanQuery.Builder();

builder.add(categoryQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);

FullTextQuery query = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(builder.build(), Product.class);

// Create the faceting request
FacetingRequest priceFacetingRequest = builder.facet()
    .name("priceFaceting")
    .onField("price")
    .range()
    .below(10).excludeLimit()
    .from(10).to(20).excludeLimit()
    .from(50).to(100).excludeLimit()
    .from(100).to(200).excludeLimit()
    .from(200).to(500).excludeLimit()
    .from(500).to(1000).excludeLimit()
    .above(1000)
    .createFacetingRequest();

// retrieve facet manager and apply faceting request
FacetManager facetManager = fullTextQuery.getFacetManager();
facetManager.enableFaceting(priceFacetingRequest);

// Retrieve the faceting results
List<Facet> facets = facetManager.getFacets("priceFaceting");

// Process the facets
// The list will contain one element per facet defined above,
// i.e. "(-infinity,10)", "[10,20)", "[50,100)", "[100,200)", "[200,500)", "[500,1000)","[1000,+infinity)"
// Note that by defaults, facets with 0 matching document will be omitted.
for (Facet facet : facets) {
    String rangeAsString = facet.getValue();
    int matchingDocumentCount = facet.getCount();
    // ... do something with the data ...
}
```

`facets` will then contain each relevant facet for your search.

Comment: Thank you ..this solution works for getting products between min and max price..suppose there is 10000 products in clothing category i just want to get min price and maximum price from this products..i am passing this data using pagination so it is not possible solution to iterate all list n get min and max price...is there any solution for this functionality??

Comment: As I said in the beginning of my message, no, there is no feature in Hibernate Search allowing you to get the min and max. But I am not sure you understood what I suggested; the returned `facets` list will only contain the categories, not the results themselves. And you can totally skip the call to `getResultList. So the fact there are 10,000 products does not really matter, you won't load these products. I'll edit my message.

Comment: Note that if faceting is not enough for your use case, and you're interested in aggregations (min/max, sum, average, ....), you can follow progress on this ticket: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-3003